# Use if statement in layout.html.erb in a Sinatra app

Tags: css, ruby, sinatra

Within my Sinatra application I would like to serve a minified version of my css/js for production but in development keep my default setup (individual files). I'm not quite sure how to write this in the correct syntax but if I give a pseudo-example, it should show what I am trying to achieve.

layout.html.erb

```
<% if :environment == :development %>
  <!-- stylesheet link tags here -->
<% elsif :environment == :production %>
  <!-- minified versions of stylesheets -->
<% end %>
```

is it possible to conditionally set which stylesheets I want to use, or is there a better way of doing this?

I am trying this

```
<% if ENV['RACK_ENV] = 'development' %>
  <!-- stylesheet link tags here -->
<% elsif ENV['RACK_ENV] = 'production' %>
 <!-- minified versions of stylesheets -->
<% end %>
```

Is there a more efficient way than this?

Comment: In your first example you have `:environment == :development` which will always be false since you are comparing two different symbols. [Sinatra provides `development?`, `test?` and `production?` methods](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Environments) that make checking the environment easy.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it yet, but it looks like [sinatra-assetpack](http://ricostacruz.com/sinatra-assetpack/) would provide an excellent solution for your problem.